# Star Trek episode where Riker and Troi had a daughter in a time-shift?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I recall a time-shift episode where Commander Riker and Deanna Troi had a relationship and bore a daughter. The daughter was called Shinara. My wife and I had seen a re-run in around 1992 and subsequently named our daughter Shinara in December 1994.

Have been trying to track down this episode to share with our daughter. Would greatly appreciate any leads from all the highly knowledgeable and passionate fans of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.

Comment: Great name for a girl!

Comment: Nothing I can add to the answer below - as soon as I saw the question I knew the answer but was beaten to it - but what a lovely story, Keith! Thank you for sharing it.

The closest I can offer is we used to have a cat named Irska, Deltan for Bright Star, from the original version of The Child from Phase II when it was Ilia rather than Deanna who was impregnated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The episode you are looking for is "[Parallels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode))", and it's not Riker and Troi's child.. It's Worf and Troi's. See the Memory Alpha article on that episode or [Shannara](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shannara)'s page.

The episode is most commonly remembered as the one with the thousands of Enterprises appearing from different universes, including one with a freaked out Riker who claimed that in his Universe the Borg had won.

[image: Riker stares out of the viewscreen from an empty bridge; his beard is long and his hair is messy; he looks stunned or shell-shocked]

Comment: Dear KHW. Thank you so very much for your response. I guess we ended up spelling the name differently! She will be delighted to watch this episode. Regards.

Comment: That scene with the freaked out Riker is probably one my favourite of the series!

Comment: We call that "*Castaway* Riker"

Comment: "Captain,  we are receiving 285,000 hails." Best line in the entire series.